How to project a 3D cuboid onto a 2D camera image?
I'm working on a project where I need to render a 3D cuboid onto a 2D camera image. The image should be displayed with a width of 600px, maintaining its aspect ratio. Here are the details of my cuboid and camera calibration:
const cuboidData = {
    "id": "c90193ab-1812-4b52-a853-030d44a901fd",
    "objType": "3D_BOX",
    "viewIndex": 0,
    "center3D": { "x": 23.708989938369655, "y": -4.249143642992031, "z": 0 },
    "rotation3D": { "x": 0, "y": 0, "z": -1.5707965497209813 },
    "size3D": { "x": 2.0937808419650805, "y": 2.832762406310554, "z": 0.2 }
};


const cameraCalibration = {
    "camera_matrix": [7265.09513308939, 0.0, 2099.699693520321, 0.0, 0.0, 7265.09513308939, 1217.709330768128, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
    "distortion_coeffs": [-0.0878118, 0.0196239, 0.0, 0.0, 0.902557],
    "width_px": 4112,
    "height_px": 2504
};


const coordSystem = {
    "translation": [0.0609096, -0.136682, 3.51522],
    "quaternion": [-0.0121052, 0.0606543, 0.188524, 0.980119]
};

How can I correctly handle the camera calibration and transformations to render the 3D cuboid accurately on the 2D image?

why use SVG? Shouldn't you be using webgl instead?

anything is fine at the end. I just want to render the cuboid on the image

same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78788774/rendering-a-3d-cuboid-onto-a-camera-image-using-svg-in-three-js
